# How to expand VIM emmet abbreviation

Tags: vim, emmet

I am trying to expand a emmet abbreviation in vim.   for example in insert mode I type in html:5,  then I press `<C-y>`,  which I believe is supposed to expand the abbreviation.  However, nothing happens.

Comment: It's `Ctrl+y` followed by `,`. As explained in the ["quick tutorial"](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim#quick-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Emmet's default abbreviation to expand an abbreviation is `<Ctrl-y>,`, not just `<Ctrl-y>`. Here are the other commands that are included with vim-emmet:

```
<C-Y>A        emmet-anchorize-summary
<C-Y>a        emmet-anchorize-url
<C-Y>k        emmet-remove-tag
<C-Y>j        emmet-split-join-tag
<C-Y>/        emmet-toggle-comment
<C-Y>i        emmet-image-size
<C-Y>N        emmet-move-prev
<C-Y>n        emmet-move-next
<C-Y>D        emmet-balance-tag-outword
<C-Y>d        emmet-balance-tag-inward
<C-Y>u        emmet-update-tag
<C-Y>;        emmet-expand-word
<C-Y>,        emmet-expand-abbr
```